# How is the title bar hidden?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I'm looking at the demo app of [MaterialDesignLibrary](https://github.com/navasmdc/MaterialDesignLibrary/tree/master/MaterialDesignLibrary/MaterialDesignDemo).

In its [manifest](https://github.com/navasmdc/MaterialDesignLibrary/blob/master/MaterialDesignLibrary/MaterialDesignDemo/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml), it uses the `AppTheme`

`<application android:allowBackup="true" android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:theme="@style/AppTheme">`

The `AppTheme` is simply `Theme.Light`

```
<resources>

    <!--
        Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
        by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.
    -->
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
        <!--
            Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
            res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
            backward-compatibility can go here.
        -->
    </style>

    <!-- Application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
        <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
    </style>

</resources>
```

However, if I use the same theme in my app, I get a title bar but not in theirs (both using the layout previewer and the emulator). Does anyone know how they manage to hide the title bar? I know how hiding can be achieved, but I'm trying to follow their approach.

Here's what the previewer shows when the demo app is loaded

[image]

There's no action bar in the layout previewer for their app, but there is for mine - even with `Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE` set. Here's mine:

[image]

Thanks

**EDIT** Here's my code

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="148dp" >

        <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="128dp"
                android:background="#01579b"
                android:paddingBottom="20dp"
                android:paddingLeft="104dp" android:id="@+id/">

            <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:text="MaterialDesign"
                    android:textColor="#FFF"
                    android:textSize="25dp" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <View
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="2dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="128dp"
                android:background="#88CECECE" />

        <com.gc.materialdesign.views.ButtonFloatSmall
                android:id="@+id/buttonColorSelector"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="108dp"
                android:background="#1E88E5"
                materialdesign:iconDrawable="@drawable/icn_select_color" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity.java:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.tagapp.tagapp" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

build.grade:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Module build.grade:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.1'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.tagapp.tagapp"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you look at their code in [`MainActivity.java`](https://github.com/navasmdc/MaterialDesignLibrary/blob/master/MaterialDesignLibrary/MaterialDesignDemo/src/main/java/com/gc/materialdesigndemo/ui/MainActivity.java), right at the beginning of `onCreate()` they use `Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE`

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    /* ... */
```

So, no magic here.

---

I finally came around testing this on my system. Removing the line

```
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

shows the title bar again. Of course, the other activities hide the title bar, because each of them (`Buttons`, `Progress`, `Switch` and `Widget`) have the same code in `onCreate()`. Removing the line there as well has the same effect, showing the title bar!

---

I cannot comment on some previewer, because I never heard of that before.

Comment: No, even with it removed, there's no title bar shown in the previewer or in the emulator. That's what's so mystifying... Plus, I don't think the previewer interprets the body of onCreate() - right?

Answer (score 0):

You should change the parent parameter to Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar to hide the action bar in your application.

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>
```

Comment: Well, I know how hiding can be achieved, but I'm trying to follow how the demo app did it. I don't see them using that parent though. Their style looks like `<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">`.

Comment: @Kar Maybe the demo app have this element in style tag `<item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>`

Comment: I don't think it does. I already pasted their `styles.xml` in my question and it's very simple.

Comment: Did you see all resource folders for style.xml file? maybe there is another style.xml!

Comment: That's what I thought too, but there's only one. In fact, if I change the manifest to `<application android:allowBackup="true" android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:theme="@style/Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">` there'd still be no title/action bar in the previewer.

Comment: Did you try to click on refresh button on previewer after you made the change? could you past your style.xml file here, not the demo's file.

Comment: Well, because I'm trying to imitate the demo app, I'm using their styles.xml. It has just two style stubs exactly like the demo app's. Like Olaf pointed out, the demo app has `requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);` in the onCreate(), but removing it still gives no bar in the demo app. Plus, I don't think the previewer interprets the body of `onCreate()`.

Comment: In the preview panel you have an option to change the API level of device to have preview of your layout, try to use lower API level and see the result. Did you run the application on a real device?

Comment: I've tried 22 and 21 and the demo app still manages to hide the bar in both, even when the DarkActionBar theme is used.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this code will be useful, try put this in your activity (onCreate method):

```
this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();

if(actionBar != null) {
    actionBar.hide();
}
```

Comment: I'm actually hoping to follow their approach, which is quite obscure it seems. I know how hiding can be done, but I can't quite see how the demo app does it.